# Code Formatter not working good for Flutter VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am unable to format my flutter code properly.

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have missing this code in your setting.json

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

kindly add hope so problem solved